# Python Tkinter: Functions as variables. How to check if a function parameter exists in a .txt file?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, parameters

I am writing a login system with tkinter. I am trying to check if a user input, a username (`user_entry`), exists in a .txt file. If the username exists, I want to display an error.

I am trying to pass the entry input, `user_entry`, into the lambda here:

```
button1 = Button(topwindow, text='Submit', command=lambda: [checkinfo(user_entry.get()), saveinfo(user_entry.get(), password_entry.get()), displaymessage1()])
```

I want to pass the `user.entry.get()` into the `checkinfo` function to see if the username exists in the .txt file where I am storing the usernames and passwords. Here are the two relevant functions, `signup` and `checkinfo`.

```
def checkinfo(user_entry):

    with open('userdata2.txt') as file:
        if user_entry in csv.reader(file):
            print("Username already taken. Please chose a different username.")
        else:
            pass



def signup():

    topwindow = Toplevel()
    topwindow.geometry("400x400")

    label1 = Label(topwindow, text='Please select username and password.', font=('Arial', 19))
    label1.pack()

    label2 = Label(topwindow, text="Select a username.")
    label2.pack()

    user_entry = Entry(topwindow)
    user_entry.pack()

    label3 = Label(topwindow, text="Select a password.")
    label3.pack()

    password_entry = Entry(topwindow)
    password_entry.pack()

    button1 = Button(topwindow, text='Submit', command=lambda: [checkinfo(user_entry.get()), saveinfo(user_entry.get(), password_entry.get()), displaymessage1()])
    button1.pack()
```

No matter what I do, the program runs does not run `checkinfo` correctly. The function is not checking the .txt file to see if the username exists, and it just keeps adding it. I am unsure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: The elements of `csv.reader(file)` are going to be entire rows from the file - in the form of lists, I think.  `user_entry` is a string, and cannot possibly be equal to any of those lists.  You would need to loop through the file contents yourself, and check the specific of each row that holds the usernames against the user entry.

Comment: I see. So what would the syntax for this look like? I would have to loop over each row, split the items on the ',' and then see if the user_entry is present. But I am confused as to how to do this correctly while reading from the .txt file using csv.reader(filer).